# Random "The destination file has an extension that may be blocked" on JobTask export

Tags: web-services, soap, navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

I have an inherited problem with Navision 2016 ODATA web service I use in my application.

Normally it works well, but randomly (1 per 100 runs aprox.) it faults with the following stack log:

```
Server instance: NAV Tenant ID: User: Type: Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Types.Exceptions.NavNCLXmlPortNodeProcessException SuppressMessage: False SuppressExceptionCreatedEvent: False FatalityScope: None Message: Could not process node JobTask. The following error occurred: The file that you are trying to create cannot be created. The destination file has an extension that may be blocked. Contact your system administrator. StackTrace:
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPortExporter.TryProcessElement(NavXmlPortNode node)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPortExporter.LoopElementChildren(NavXmlPortNode node)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPortExporter.ProcessTextElement(NavXmlPortTextNode node)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPortExporter.ProcessElement(NavXmlPortNode node)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPortExporter.TryProcessElement(NavXmlPortNode node)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPortExporter.Export()
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPort.Export(DataError errorLevel)
     at Filter.InvokeWithFilter(NavMethodScope )
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavMethodScope.Run()
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.BusinessApplication.Codeunit50005.ExportJobTask(NavXmlPortHandle jobTaskXML)   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.TaskHelper.Rethrow(Exception exception)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Service.WebServices.ServiceBroker.Invoke(Boolean isSoapMessage, Uri url, XmlReader input, TextWriter output, NavUserAuthentication navUserAuth)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Service.WebServices.NavWebService.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ProcessMessage>b__3()
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Service.WebServices.Disposer.Scope(Code code)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Service.WebServices.WCFUtil.GetPopulatedMemoryStream(StreamFillingCallback callback)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Service.WebServices.NavWebService.ProcessMessage(Message message)
     at SyncInvokeProcessMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet) Source: Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Ncl HResult:
-2146233088
---------------------------------- Type: Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Types.Exceptions.NavNCLFileLoadException SuppressMessage: False SuppressExceptionCreatedEvent: False FatalityScope: None Message: Could not process node JobTask. The following error occurred: The file that you are trying to create cannot be created. The destination file has an extension that may be blocked. Contact your system administrator. StackTrace:
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavFile.InternalCreateOrOpen(DataError errorLevel, FileOption options, Boolean checkFileType)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavFile.ALCreate(DataError errorLevel, String createName, TextEncoding encoding)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavBLOB.ALExport(String fileName)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.BusinessApplication.XMLport50000.Job_Task_a45_Exporta58a58OnAfterGetRecord_Scope.OnRun()
     at Filter.InvokeWithFilter(NavMethodScope )
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavMethodScope.Run()
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.BusinessApplication.XMLport50000.Job_Task_a45_Exporta58a58OnAfterGetRecord()
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPortTableNode.FireExportTrigger(NavTrigger trigger)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPortExporter.ProcessTableElement(NavXmlPortTableNode node)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPortExporter.ProcessElement(NavXmlPortNode node)
     at Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Runtime.NavXmlPortExporter.TryProcessElement(NavXmlPortNode node) Source: Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Ncl HResult: -2146233088
```

Do you have any idea what could be the origin of this error?

Comment: Check Codeunit 50005 and XMLport 50000.  These are not standard Microsoft objects, but customisations.

Comment: Thank you @ian_scho. I am aware that those classes are customisations. Our NAV2016 has many customisations like this but only JobTask faults this way. Anyhow we applied the solution proposed by Jake and for the moment it works perfectly. We will wait for few days more and will mark it as resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the random filename it's choosing matches the list of prohibited file extensions in the Service Tier configuration? Could explain why it's so random.

Try disabling this option temporarily to see whether it resolves the issue. I'd consider it a platform bug, so it should be reported to Microsoft.

[image: Set prohibited extensions]

The following extensions are blocked by default:

> ade;adp;app;asp;bat;bas;chm;cmd;com;cpl;csh;exe;fxp;gadget;hlp;hta;inf;ins;isp;its;js;jse;ksh;lnk;mad;maf;mag;mam;maq;mar;mas;mat;mau;mav;maw;mda;mdb;mde;mdt;mdw;mdz;msc;msi;msp;mst;ops;pcd;pif;prf;prg;pst;reg;scf;scr;sct;shb;shs;url;vb;vbe;vbs;vsmacros;vss;vst;vsw;ws;wsc;wsf;wsh

Comment: One week since we applied the solution. 0 faults by now.  Thank you, Jake, great answer